# Firefox and toFixed()

Tags: javascript, firefox

When i do

```
$("#sum").html(parseFloat("2.2").toFixed(2));
```

In firefox i get:

```
"<b xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">2.20</b>"
```

in

```
 $("#sum").html()
```

I want to calculate (and display correct) with this div (#sum) what is not possible, because i get the float value with

```
sum = parseFloat($("#summe").html());
```

and it returns NaN.

This works with Chrome. Is there any way to get this to work with firefox?

Comment: Do you actually have an element with ID `summe`, or is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) in both cases rather than `.html()`, since you are only setting text.

```
// Set
$("#sum").text(parseFloat("2.2").toFixed(2));

// Get (don't forget `var` if you're declaring here)
sum = parseFloat($("#summe").text());
```